# How does a complete computer idiot like me upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have just clicked and run Ubuntu in preference to the Windows side of the HD, but it appears that I am running an old version and that I need to upgrade, but I believe that I can't go straight from 10. something to the current  one. Also try as I may I cant get my printer to work with Ubuntu although it used to. flash player useless as well

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu version is really old, the best suggestion from me would be to download the latest Ubuntu (12.04) and freshly install it, rather than having to update packages, do some settings, make backup then finally upgrade. Plus you should know that when upgrading there is more chance of.....how can I say it........screwing up your PC (lots of files missing, bugs etc etc its a long list) and end up getting into a big mess and as you said it 'computer idiot' you won't be able to handle it.

Trust me its for your own good.
Download the latest Ubuntu from here >> http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Comment: It looks like he's using Wubi.

Comment: If this is a wubi installation be very very careful.  You can trash Windows as well as Ubuntu if you get it wrong.  How do you find out?  If you know what method was used to install it and can tell us in detail, we can help.  If not, get the DVD (as in the above answer) and boot into it - DON'T try to put the disk in while Windows is running.  This is the wubi installation.  When you have booted, you are given the option 'Try Ubuntu'.  Do this and try everything to make sure 12.04 works for you.  Then please ask again how to look at your installation from the live-DVD

Comment: Oh - and don't install or attempt to install until you have come back to us telling us what you have found out so far.